# IOS App - not receiving click input

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating an app. I've done some basic stuff so far, removed the main storyboard and added some components to the main viewcontroller with code and cartography for constraints

basically nothing is clickable, i have UITextFields that can't be focused and buttons that can't be clicked.

why this is happening? thanks

```
import UIKit
import Cartography

class LoginViewController: BaseViewController {

    var identifierField: UITextField!
    var passwordField: UITextField!

    override func loadUI() {
        view.clipsToBounds = true
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.colorPrimary()

        let logoText = UILabel()

        let loginView = UIView()

        logoText.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: NSLocalizedString("APP_NAME", comment: ""))
        logoText.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(32.0)

        self.view.addSubview(logoText)

        constrain(logoText, self.view) {
            logo, mainView in
            logo.top == mainView.top + 50
            logo.centerX == mainView.centerX
        }

        identifierField = UITextField()
        identifierField.borderStyle = .Line
        identifierField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString("USER_IDENTIFIER_PLACEHOLDER", comment: "")
        identifierField.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()


        passwordField = UITextField()
        passwordField.borderStyle = .Line
        passwordField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString("PASSWORD_PLACEHOLDER", comment: "")
        passwordField.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()


        let loginButton = UIButton()
        loginButton.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("LOGIN", comment: ""), forState: .Normal)

        let registrationButton = UIButton()
        registrationButton.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("REGISTER", comment: ""), forState: .Normal)
        registrationButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onRegistrationClicked(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        loginView.addSubview(identifierField)
        loginView.addSubview(passwordField)
        loginView.addSubview(loginButton)
        loginView.addSubview(registrationButton)

        view.addSubview(loginView)

        constrain(loginView, logoText, self.view) {
            loginView, logo, mainView in

            loginView.top == logo.bottom + 30
            loginView.width == mainView.width - 30
            loginView.centerX == mainView.centerX
        }

        constrain(loginView, identifierField, passwordField, loginButton, registrationButton) {
            loginView, identifierField, passwordField, loginButton, registrationButton in
            identifierField.top == loginView.top + 30
            identifierField.centerX == loginView.centerX
            identifierField.width == loginView.width

            passwordField.top == identifierField.bottom + 20
            passwordField.centerX == loginView.centerX
            passwordField.width == loginView.width

            loginButton.top == passwordField.bottom + 20
            loginButton.centerX == loginView.centerX
            loginButton.width == loginView.width

            registrationButton.top == loginButton.bottom + 20
            registrationButton.centerX == loginView.centerX
            registrationButton.width == loginView.width
        }
    }

    func onRegistrationClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        print("Register clicked")
        navigationController?.pushViewController(RegistrationViewController(), animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read the tour before posting a question. In short, if you don't provide any code, we can't help you. http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: You mean tapped, right? You don't "click" an iPhone screen. There is no mouse. No cursor.

Comment: my bad, yeah i mean tapped but said clicked because i'm using the simulator

Answer (score 1):

Use the userInteractionEnabled flag.
e.g., in Swift -

```
identifierField.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

Comment: This is a comment, asking for clarification is not an answer.

Comment: I don't get it. How's this not an answer? As you can see in the OP's code, this flag is missing/not set. What am I asking clarification for?